# Профиты от использования MVP

Tags: android, mvp

Я разобрался с mvp и даже dagger 2 поковырял, но для меня осталось не совсем понятным какие преимущества дает использование MVP при разработке мобильных приложений. Загуглил на эту тему и нашел даже небольшой холивар, но как мне кажется истина где то по середине. 
Скажите какие есть основания применять MVP на проекте? Пока я выделил только один - вроде как проще покрывать код тестами.

Вот кстати [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131446/) о которой я говорил.

Comment: Ну, например, можно писать тесты для presenter'а без запуска на эмуляторе/устройстве...

Comment: вы нашли один, но достаточно большой плюс, так как это достаточно важно в разработке, особенно в команде.

Comment: Поскольку "дефолтный" паттерн Android - MVC (jy естественно реализуется связкой: данные - активити- разметка, к примеру) то полезно будет почитать [данную статью](http://java-help.ru/model-view-presenter-android-part-1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVP обеспечивает модульность приложения что позволяет без болезненно менять логику или дизайн, так же читабельность кода возрастает в разы, ну и по тесты Вы уже сами написали.

Answer (score 0):

Логика выполнения приложения никак не зависит от дизайна. Если у вас поменяется логика, то вы меняете код в Presenter, но при этом вся связка приложения остается такой же.